# VB 2010 - How to Format a number

Tags: vb.net

I have a masked textbox in my program that asks the user to write a number in this mask "00". Sometimes the user only writes one number like this "4". How can i format the textbox to show "04" instead ?

Answer (score 0):

PadLeft will do it for you.

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.PadLeft(2, "0")
```

Comment: I get an error 'TextPadLeft' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.MaskedTextbox'. What must I do to enable TextPadLeft ?

Comment: Are you missing the dot in Text dot PadLeft ?

Comment: It seems I did. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: How can I make Padleft work for this mask "00.0". For example: format "4" to "04.0" ?

Answer (score 0):

Beat to the punch, but here is another method (Edited per comment):

```
Private Sub MaskedTextBox1_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MaskedTextBox1.Leave
    Do Until MaskedTextBox1.MaskFull
        MaskedTextBox1.Text = "0" & MaskedTextBox1.Text
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: That works, but I also have another masked textbox that has this mask "000". And I also want to make that format "4" to "004" or "24" to "024". The above solution doesn't work for that.

Comment: Use PadLeft to achieve your requirement.

Comment: @PanagiotisGianniotis, see edit above. Also, I believe Mort is right that you are simply missing a `.` to get `Text.PadLeft` to work.